# OSGi doPrivileged call between two bundles

Tags: java, osgi, blueprint

i have a problem using OSGi.

What i have:

- 2 simple bundles (Bundle A calls Bundle B)
- blueprint usage
- OSGi security usage
- both bundles are core bundles with all permissions
- third party bundles don't have all permissions, i.e. the PropertyPermission("bla", "write") will be denied

So as already mentioned the bundle call is pretty simple. Bundle A calls bundle B. The only complicated thing in it is, that the call is a doPrivileged call.

Following scenarios/examples:

Set a "bla" property in bundle A without doPrivileged -> fails (ok)

```
public void foo() {
 System.setProperty("bla", "blubb"); // throws java.security.AccessControlException: access denied ("java.util.PropertyPermission" "bla" "write") -> ok
}
```

Set a "bla" property in bundle A with doPrivileged -> works (ok)

```
public void foo() {
 AccessController.doPrivileged(new PrivilegedExceptionAction<Boolean>() {
    @Override
    public Boolean run()
       throws Exception
    {
       System.setProperty("bla", "blubb"); // sets the bla property without throwing an exception -> ok
       return null;
    }
 });
}
```

Now trying to set the "bla" property in bundle B using the doPrivileged call of bundle A -> fails (why?)

Bundle A:

```
public void foo() {
 AccessController.doPrivileged(new PrivilegedExceptionAction<Boolean>() {
    @Override
    public Boolean run()
       throws Exception
    {
       // calls Bundle B
       bundleBService.bar();
       return null;
    }
 });
}
```

Bundle B:

```
public void bar() {
  System.setProperty("bla", "blubb"); // throws java.security.AccessControlException: access denied ("java.util.PropertyPermission" "bla" "write")
}
```

So why does it fail to set the property in bundle B using a doPrivileged call of bundle A? I would expect, that the doPrivileged call would also work here. Why it doesn't? Is it the fault of using blueprint? And is it possible wo solve this issue without adding the doPrivileged block to the method of bundle B?

Update: Here is the StackTrace:

```
java.security.AccessControlException: access denied ("java.util.PropertyPermission" "bla" "write")
    at java.security.AccessControlContext.checkPermission(AccessControlContext.java:372)
    at java.security.AccessController.checkPermission(AccessController.java:559)
    at java.lang.SecurityManager.checkPermission(SecurityManager.java:549)
    at java.lang.System.setProperty(System.java:782)
    at barpkg.BundleB.bar(BundleB.java:35)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.apache.aries.proxy.impl.ProxyHandler$1.invoke(ProxyHandler.java:54)
    at org.apache.aries.proxy.impl.ProxyHandler.invoke(ProxyHandler.java:119)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy111.bar(Unknown Source)
    at foopkg.BundleA$1.run(BundleA.java:73)
    at foopkg.BundleA$1.run(BundleA.java:65)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at foopkg.BundleA.foo(BundleA.java:65)
    at testpkg.PrivilegedTest.testDoPrivileged(PrivilegedTest.java:135)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:44)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:26)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunAfters.evaluate(RunAfters.java:27)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:271)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:70)
    at org.ops4j.pax.exam.invoker.junit.internal.ContainerTestRunner.runChild(ContainerTestRunner.java:67)
    at org.ops4j.pax.exam.invoker.junit.internal.ContainerTestRunner.runChild(ContainerTestRunner.java:37)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:238)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:63)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:236)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:53)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:229)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:309)
    at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:160)
    at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:138)
    at org.ops4j.pax.exam.invoker.junit.internal.JUnitProbeInvoker.invokeViaJUnit(JUnitProbeInvoker.java:111)
    at org.ops4j.pax.exam.invoker.junit.internal.JUnitProbeInvoker.findAndInvoke(JUnitProbeInvoker.java:84)
    at org.ops4j.pax.exam.invoker.junit.internal.JUnitProbeInvoker.call(JUnitProbeInvoker.java:72)
    at org.ops4j.pax.exam.glassfish.GlassFishTestContainer.call(GlassFishTestContainer.java:271)
    at org.ops4j.pax.exam.spi.reactors.SingletonStagedReactor.invoke(SingletonStagedReactor.java:113)
    at org.ops4j.pax.exam.spi.reactors.PerSuiteStagedReactor.invoke(PerSuiteStagedReactor.java:47)
    at org.ops4j.pax.exam.junit.PaxExam$2.evaluate(PaxExam.java:294)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:271)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:70)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:50)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:238)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:63)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:236)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:53)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:229)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:309)
    at org.ops4j.pax.exam.junit.PaxExam.run(PaxExam.java:111)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.execute(JUnit4Provider.java:242)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.executeTestSet(JUnit4Provider.java:137)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.invoke(JUnit4Provider.java:112)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.util.ReflectionUtils.invokeMethodWithArray(ReflectionUtils.java:189)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ProviderFactory$ProviderProxy.invoke(ProviderFactory.java:165)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ProviderFactory.invokeProvider(ProviderFactory.java:85)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.runSuitesInProcess(ForkedBooter.java:115)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.main(ForkedBooter.java:75)
```

I'd guess, this lines could be the troublemakers:

```
at org.apache.aries.proxy.impl.ProxyHandler$1.invoke(ProxyHandler.java:54)
at org.apache.aries.proxy.impl.ProxyHandler.invoke(ProxyHandler.java:119)
at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy111.bar(Unknown Source)
```

I'll try to do this call without using blueprint too see, what happens. 
But if blueprint is the problem, can i somehow handle it without replacing it?

Thank you

Comment: Java security is based on stack walking. Can you show the complete stack trace of the security exception? My blind guess would be that the stack contains an underprivileged proxy.

Comment: As long as you stay on the same thread I would expect your code to work. Do you use plain OSGi API to call the service or do you use some framework?

Comment: @bkail
Edited the original Post and added the StackTrace.

Comment: @ChristianSchneider
I'm using apache aries blueprint to call the service.

Comment: I've tried it without blueprint now. Plain OSGi, a BundleActivator with start() and stop(). Now the call works as wished. It seems that blueprint causes the problems because of it's proxy use. Is it possible to make it work with blueprint - some configuration values or something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok it works now, using the aries blueprint framework as well.

I've signed the aries blueprint, proxy and utils jars manually (so they are core bundles as well) to see if this would solve the problem. Worked fine.

I'll now create a maven module, where i'll put all the blueprint bundles i need. So i can sign this bundle and don't need to sign each jar separately and also just have one bundle i'll need to deploy.